# Windsor not installing dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am very new when it comes to using dependency injection and IoC in Asp.Net. My application is layered into several directories of the same project, since this is a small project.

I have some services that I want to inject into my controllers. They all inherit from an empty interface:

[image: Basic Interface]

The installer for the services is the following:

[image: Services Installer]

And the GlobalAsax file:

[image: Global.asax.cs]

I have debugged and noticed that my ServicesInstaller class does get called, however, the dependency is not installed as in my controller the instance to one of my services is left null.

Does anyone have an idea of how I am supposed to set this up properly?

I want to be able to use my dependencies in my controllers like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    private readonly IPDFService _pdfService;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //PDFService service = new PDFService();
        string pdfFile = _pdfService.GenerateAgendaPdfFromURL("http://google.com", 1);

        return View((object)pdfFile);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try creating a constructor in TestController which takes the dependency IPDFService as argument. The container will resolve it.

Comment: It appears that you're missing the constructor on your controller that takes an `IPDFService` and assigns that parameter to `_pdfService`. I'm just guessing, though, as I don't know Windsor. Have you considered trying a lighter-weight IoC engine for your initial learning? DryIoc or Autofac would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated from [Brannon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825559/windsor-not-installing-dependencies#comment68870587_40825559), you have to add a constructor to you controller that accepts the service. Or you can change your member `private readonly IPDFService _pdfService;` to a public property. Windsor will inject properties as well.

Additionally you should add `.WithServiceSelf()` to your service registration like this:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IService>().WithServiceSelf()
```

this registers only the types of your services and not all implemented interfaces or inherited types.

Comment: Thanks man, I entirely forgot about adding it to the constructor.